# How to maintain company profile in SO careers among several users?

Tags: support, jobs, merge-accounts

I have a problem regarding stackoverflow careers.

Think my company wants to create a job listing and I am telling it to my HR manager. So he creates an account in website and he put an ad. Then he creates the company page for my website. So after 6 month he is resigning from our company and we don't have any communication with him. Even if we do he refuse to give his login details to stackoverflow careers page. So how do I reclaim my website profile and assigned its login credentials for my next HR user? If we make a new account how to merge them?

When talking about claiming process How SO knows the claiming person is really an employee in my company.? That could be anyone right?

Comment: Make sure the login credentials are stored (_securely_) somewhere locally, where you can access it, while that HR manager is still your HR manager.

Comment: Or isn't this a "What if...?", but a "What now...?" instead?

Answer (score 5):

You should create a new account and then contact careers@stackoverflow.com with the relevant details and we'll take care of merging it for you.

Comment: What are these relevant details? How SO knows the claiming person is really an employee in my company.? That could be anyone right?

Comment: I imagine an email from the company, or maybe even contact by phone could be involved.

Comment: Come on man email? You can have a email with the same name of the company. Today its not that hard to register for an email. :) . how SO know that email is my companies email?

Comment: If the email's sent to / from, say, _info@company.com_, that'd be relatively difficult to fake. I'm kindof confused what the point of this question is, though. Do you actually need to reclaim an account, or is this all speculation?

Comment: @Sylar Cerbrus is correct. Send us the email addresses used by each account *from* a company email address and so long as everything looks legit we'll do the merge for you. I'm not sure what the problem is here.